# how to deploy additional files to azure?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-files

I try to deploy a file for download to azure together with my web application.

The file is part of my project in a folder in my VS2010 solution. In the file properties, I tried both, setting the Build Action to "Content" or setting "Copy to output" to always. After deployment, the file is not there, I get a 404. Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Just to be clear, did you set build action to Content AND Copy to output to always? Or did you just set one and then the other?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to provide a file for download, you may want to look at hosting that file in a storage account in BLOB storage.  You could then leverage the CDN to provide better performance to your end users in their download experience.

As for troubleshooting your existing problem, here are some ideas...

You probably only need to be setting the build action to "Content".  That should do the trick for making sure that your file is being included when you publish your web application.

One thing you can do to make sure is to right click your web application project in Solution Explorer and publish it to the file system.  Then you can inspect it to make sure your files are staged appropriately.

You could even go the extent of using the new Remote Desktop capabilities in the 1.3 SDK to remote into your Web Role instance in the cloud and inspect how your package was deployed.